# couldn't pass `gurobi.GenExpr` into `model.setObjective`

Tags: python, gurobi

```
from gurobipy import *

global_model = Model("_")

schedule = [global_model.addVar(name=x) for x in ["alpha", "beta"]]
maxtime = max_(schedule)

global_model.update()
global_model.setObjective(maxtime, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

I just init a list of `gurobi.Var` (`schedule`) and I want to minimize the max value of them (`maxtime`). But it seems impossible to simply make `maxtime` the 1st arg for `setObjective`:

> gurobipy.GurobiError: Unable to convert argument to an expression

How how do I fix it?

Comment: Better late than never: If my answer was helpful, you may consider accepting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's uncommon to create a list of gurobi variables. In general, better use [Model.addVars()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html#pythonmethod:Model.addVars) to get a gurobi tupledict of your variables. And as far as I remember correctly, you can use `max_()` only inside the Model.addConstr() and [Model.addConstrs()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html#pythonmethod:Model.addConstrs) methods.

To sum it up, here's a way to do it:

```
alpha = global_model.addVar(name="alpha")
beta = global_model.addVar(name="beta")
maxtime = global_model.addVar(name="maxtime")
global_model.update()
global_model.addConstr(maxtime == max_(alpha, beta))
global_model.setObjective(maxtime, sense=GRB.MINIMIZE)
```